# Creating a console app that writes line of output and exits upon Ctrl+C

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I want to create a Console app that outputs a 'summary statement' as the last line of output, when it is terminated using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, but I'm having trouble getting this working. This may be in part due to app I'm trying to create is constantly writing output in a `while(true)` loop. I can best illustrate the problem with an simple example:

Let's say I have a console app that constantly outputs the current time:

```cs
while (true)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.Write(now);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(now.Millisecond);
    Console.CursorLeft = 0; // Overwrite the same line
}
```

This works and I can terminate the app with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>:

```
23/02/2023 23:07:14 658
```

Now when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> I want the text `Goodbye!` displayed as the final line of output:

```
23/02/2023 23:09:56 441
Goodbye!
```

However, I'm having trouble getting this working. Here's my first attempt:

```cs
Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancel;

while (true)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.Write(now);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(now.Millisecond);
    Console.CursorLeft = 0; // Overwrite the same line
}

void OnCancel(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
}
```

However, this results 'garbled' output, for example:

```
Goodbye023 23:14:55 670
23/02/2023 23:14:55
```

I think this is happening because the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event handler is executed on a separate worker thread and the call to `Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");` can happen at any point within the while loop. Ideally the `CancelKeyPress` event handler isn't ran until current iteration of the `while` loop is finished. I'm not sure how to do this in a thread-safe way.

I've tried different approaches, and I won't listed code for them, but in summary all of the following I've tried to no avail:

1. Defined a boolean variable `cancelRequested` in the top scope and set `while`
   loop condition to `!cancelRequested`; In `OnCancel` set the var to `true`;
   `Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!")` after the loop. This blocks on the
   `Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!")` line (deadlock?).
2. Similar to above but used `CancellationTokenSource` instead of a boolean variable.
   Same deadlock behavior is observed, so I guess this is equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean by "blocks" in option 1? I don't think that is possible. A deadlock isn't possible since you only have one writer.

Comment: Follow option 1, but then in `OnCancel` add `e.Cancel = true;` after setting the `cancelRequested` to `true`.

Comment: You'll need something either like https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.notnetcoreapp.cs or https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.netcoreapp.cs depending on runtime. Or, just use the generic host to track that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#host-shutdown

Comment: Also, each `Console.` operation may be thread safe, but you are calling 4 in a row, plus the call in your `OnCancel` that will be triggered from a different thread.

Comment: You're correct in your observation that the Console.CancelKeyPress event handler is executed on a separate worker thread and can interrupt the loop at any point. To ensure that the final "Goodbye!" message is only printed after the current iteration of the loop is complete, you can use a ManualResetEventSlim object to signal when the loop is done, and wait for this signal in the event handler.

Comment: @Huminteu I think you're on to something; I had a feeling some kind of signalling object would be needed (my concurrent programming experience is limited). Please do write up an answer if you have the time so I can give you credit 

Comment: Actually, @NetMage is right - no `ManuelResetEventSlim` object is needed afterall. See my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @NetMage in the comments, my first attempt to solve the issue with the garbled text using a boolean variable was not working because normally pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> terminates the app at the end of the `CancelKeyPress` and hadn't realised that I need to supress the default behavior by setting `ConsoleCancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `true`. Now that I know this, I have a working solution:

```cs
Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancel;
bool cancelRequested = false;

while (!cancelRequested)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.Write(now);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.Write(now.Millisecond);
    Console.CursorLeft = 0; // Overwrite the same line
}
    
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");

void OnCancel(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;        // Stops cancel key press from terminating the app
    cancelRequested = true; // Signal the main loop the request to cancel
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that is a general pattern to follow: when writing a custom event handler, if it processes the event you want to prevent the standard event handling from occurring as well.